# R label values in a function for many variables

Tags: r, function

I have 100 variables.
Variable names are like from "var1b" to "var100b".
I can label values each variable but don't want to repeat 100 times.
So, I tried a function to minimize the repeat.

```
valuelabel <- function(varname){
                 varname <- factor(varname, 
                 levels=c(0,1),labels=c("No","Yes"))
                               }
valuelabel(df$var1b)
table(df$var1b)
```

Table does not show the labels.
Please tell me what's wrong and would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: haven't looked at this too closely, but does assigning the return value (`df$var1b <- valuelabel(df$var1b)`) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider assigning multiple columns with an apply function:

```r
valuelabel <- function(varname) factor(
    varname, levels=c(0,1), labels=c("No","Yes")
)

var_cols <- paste0("var", 1:100, "b")

df[var_cols] <- lapply(df[var_cols], valuelabel)
```